# ui-grid display cell as select tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, angular-ui-grid, dropdown

I have an example of ui-grid that one of the column represent sex type ('Gender':male , female..). 
The json data that binding to the grid contain just the code type like (1, 2, 3...)
But I want to display the sex name like 'male' if the code is 1 and so on 
And when the user choose from list new gender i want to display the new sex name 
And update the sex code in the json data.

In fact, it was so far when I used basic HTML table (I add example in plnkr link)

any idea ?

// Code goes here and link for plunker :http://plnkr.co/edit/g6xYama3MidekeDqI3p8?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.grid', 'ui.grid.edit','ui.grid.cellNav']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.genderTypes = [{
      ID: 1,
      type: 'male'
    }, {
      ID: 2,
      type: 'female'
    }, {
      ID: 3,
      type: 'both'
    }, {
      ID: 4,
      type: 'none'
    }, ];


    $scope.gridOptions = {
      enableSorting: true,
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCellEditOnFocus: true,
      columnDefs: [{
        field: 'name',
        sort: {
          direction: 'desc',
          priority: 1
        }
      }, {
        field: 'gender',
        editType: 'dropdown',
        enableCellEdit: true,
        editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
        editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.genderTypes,
        editDropdownIdLabel: 'ID',
        editDropdownValueLabel: 'type'
      }, {
        field: 'company',
        enableSorting: false
      }],
      onRegisterApi: function(gridApi) {
        grid = gridApi.grid;
      }
    };
    $scope.gridOptions.data = [ { "name": "Ethel Price", "gender": "1", "company": "Enersol" }, { "name": "Claudine Neal", "gender": "2", "company": "Sealoud" }, { "name": "Beryl Rice", "gender": "3", "company": "Velity" }, { "name": "Wilder Gonzales", "gender": "4", "company": "Geekko" }, { "name": "Georgina Schultz", "gender": "1", "company": "Suretech" }]


  }
]);
```

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply a cell filter. I've forked your plunkr with a solution.

**Filter:**

```
app.filter('mapGender', function() {
  var genderHash = {
    1: 'male',
    2: 'female',
    3: 'both',
    4: 'none'
  };

  return function(input) {
    if (!input){
      return '';
    } else {
      return genderHash[input];
    }
  };
});
```

**Column Def:**

```
{
    field: 'gender',
    editType: 'dropdown',
    cellFilter: 'mapGender',
    enableCellEdit: true,
    editableCellTemplate: 'ui-grid/dropdownEditor',
    editDropdownOptionsArray: $scope.genderTypes,
    editDropdownIdLabel: 'ID',
    editDropdownValueLabel: 'type'
}
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/hnaMJjBGaQgMGcgt3Hc2?p=preview

**References:**

- Custom UI-Grid Filters: http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_custom_filters
- Angular Filter: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter